Oracle REGEXP_LIKE fails to recognize valid input
I was looking for a way to validate US ZIP codes and got an answer here.
I tested it using regex101 site and confirmed.
However, when I use the same expression in an Oracle stored procedure and pass the exact same input, it fails to recognize it.
The regular expression checks if input is 5 or 9 digits, or 5 digits + dash + 4 digits, and does not start with 3 or more zeros.
^(?!000)\d{5}(-\d{4})?$

Using input 08731-5107, it passes regex test, but fails in this Oracle query:
IF REGEXP_LIKE(LVPOSTCODE, '^(?!000)\d{5,9}$') OR REGEXP_LIKE(LVPOSTCODE, '^(?!000)\d{5}(-\d{4})?$') THEN ...

where LVPOSTCODE is 08731-5107.
Can someone tell me if I am doing something wrong for the above to fail?

Oracle database supports only POSIX standard of regex.Hence you have to convert your regex to POSIX standard OR With inputs from this answer
IF you have java installed in your database you can use the below
    CREATE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED RegexpMatch AS
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class RegexpMatch {
      public static int match(
        final String value,
        final String regex
      ){
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        return pattern.matcher(value).matches() ? 1 : 0;
      }
    }

Then wrap it in an SQL function
    CREATE FUNCTION regexp_java_match(value IN VARCHAR2, regex IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER
    AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'RegexpMatch.match( java.lang.String, java.lang.String ) return int';
    /

And use like the below
IF regexp_java_match(LVPOSTCODE, '^(?!000)\d{5,9}$')=1
then
 --do processing
 end if;


Thank you for the response. I don't believe we have Java installed on DB server. Even if it was, I had to go through hoops to have this set up. Too much red tape. I found that I can replace that expression with ^'([1-9]\d{4}|0[1-9]\d{3}|00[1-9]\d{2})(-\d{4})?$'. Now it works fine. Apparently, zero-width assertions are not directly supported by Oracle.
